# WordApi 1.3 incompatible with Volume License Office 2016

Tags: ms-word, office-js

We recently created a Word Add-in that uses WordApi 1.3. A client of ours uses a Volume License (VL) version of Word 2016 [`Word 2016 MSO (16.0.4849.1000) 32-bit`].

As per the [Word Javascript API requirement set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets) the Office 2016 version build should be at least `Version 1612 (Build 7668.1000)`. The client's version/build is indeed not supported, since the add-in does not sideload and is not visible to them in the AppSource store.

Our app's requirements are:

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.1" />
    <Set Name="AddInCommands" MinVersion="1.1" />
    <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.3" />
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Is there an update/patch available for the VL version of Word 2016 that adds support for WordApi 1.3?

Does VL Word 2019 support WordApi 1.3?

Is there any solution or workaround to get the add-in to work on the client's build?

Since many corporations are likely to use a Volume License version of Word, it seems odd that these versions are behind in terms of compatibility with add-in features.

Thanks in advance,

Morgan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported on Word 2019 (non-subscription). It will not be backported to Word 2016 (non-subscription).

Answer (score 0):

I think because of the limitations of the 2016 VL version the only sensible way forward is to develop a native application. You could use your javascript version as a template for the developer so it probably wouldn't be too time consuming to develop.

I think you may also be able to choose between VB.net and C#, making it not too difficult.

Good luck